# asp.net(mvc) not consuming any thread while waiting for a chat message using async/await?

Tags: asp.net, jersey, async-await

What I want to do is to achieve 100% thread agility with asp.net 4.5 async/await while waiting for a chat message (or a MSMQ message)to come. Async/await can release the HTTP request handling thread to the thread pool, but how to not use any thread while waiting for chat messages to come?

In java, I can use the latest Jersey rest API to achieve this using the @ManagedAsync/@Suspended annotation:

```
// Java code, using Jersey rest API
@Path("/Chatroom")
public class ChatHandler {
    private static final HashMap<Integer, AsyncResponse> map = new HashMap<>();

    @GET
    @Path("/JoinRoom")
    @ManagedAsync
    public void joinRoom(@PathParam("UserId") String id, @Suspended final AsyncResponse ar) {
        map.put(i, ar);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/PostChat")
    public String sendChat(@PathParam("UserId") String id, @QueryParam("message") String message) throws InterruptedException {
        map.get(i).resume(message);
        return "Message successfully sent to user " + id;
    }
}
```

Here is a description for the above code. John first uses a URL like [this](http://www.myexample.com/Chatroom/JoinRoom/john) to join the chat room as user john in order to receive some chat messages. In the corresponding method joinRoom(), Jersey will, same as async/await in asp.net 4.5, return the http request thread back into the thread pool. However here I put the HttpContext, in Jersey the AsyncResponse object, in a hashmap for later use.

Then say for the next 50 seconds, there is nobody sending chat messages, the backend Jersey server will not use any threads on anything during that 50 seconds. No thread is spent on waiting for the next chat message. Then on the 51st second, Mary goes to the [URL](http://www.myexample.com/Chatroom/PostChat/john?message=hello,) to send a hello message to user john. In sendChat() method, I retrive the HttpContext (AsyncResponse) from the hash map, and resume it with the chat message. At this time, Jersey will find an available thread in the http request thread pool to resume the AsyncResponse and send the chat message "hello" to John's browser. Mary's browser will see "Message successfully sent to user john".

So how can I acheive the same 100% thread agility with asp.net async/await? In my await method, I can not find a correct way to wait for the chat message without occupying a worker thread.

Comment: A comment about your code, as you are resuming the async response connection with John inside your sendChat method, then Mary is only going to be able to send one message to John because the suspended response completes; unless he joins the room again, is that true?

Comment: That is correct. This specific demo is only to suspend one connection (in this case John's), till another user sends him a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an ASP.NET system designed for this: SignalR. It was designed with `async` in mind, so it makes optimum use of threads.

If you don't want to use SignalR, you can use any of a number of asynchronous coordination primitives. TPL Dataflow may be a good fit for this kind of scenario, or you can use `SemaphoreSlim` or `TaskCompletionSource` or any of the [primitives in my AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: Thank you Stephen. TaskCompletionSource is what I was looking for. I can simply set the result of the TaskCompletionSource when the external messages arrive.